# Does a fractal exist for any given dimension?

Tags: fractals, dimension-theory-analysis

For example a Sierpinski Triangle has a dimension of $log_23 \approx 1.58 $, so if I named a dimension such as $log_2301$ is there definitely a fractal that exists in that dimension?

Comment: The result is true if the dimension is between 0 and 1. See the paper "Estimating the fractal dimension of sets determined by nonergodic parameters" (https://aimsciences.org/journals/displayArticlesnew.jsp?paperID=14392). Perhaps this fact can be used to deal with the general case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From

> Mohsen Soltanifar, On A Sequence of Cantor Fractals, Rose Hulman Undergraduate Mathematics Journal, Vol 7, No 1, paper 9, 2006

Theorem:  For any given $r > 0$, there are uncountable fractals with Hausdorff dimension $r$ in $n$-dimensional Euclidean space $\mathbb{R}^n$ ($n \geq - \lfloor -r \rfloor$).

The parenthetical condition just means we don't try to cram a $>n$ dimensional fractal into a $n$ dimensional space.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there are indeed aleph-two of them !

> Soltanifar M. A Generalization of the Hausdorff Dimension Theorem for Deterministic Fractals. Mathematics. 2021; 9(13):1546. https://doi.org/10.3390/math9131546

Theorem(The Generalized Hausdorff Dimension Theorem). For any real $r>0$ and $l≥0,$ there are aleph-two (symmetric) fractals with the Hausdorff dimension $r.1_{\{0\}}(l)+n.1_{(0,∞)}(l)$ and Lebesgue measure l in $R^n$ where $(⌈r⌉≤n).$